# CryptoJs equivalent of nodejs crypto function

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

I have an decryption function that uses crypto from nodejs to decrypt them. But I would like to conver them to CryptoJs library. So far when I checked cryptoJs documentation, I am unable to figure out any equivalent function for them.

```js
export const decryptURl=(string)=>{
    const CRYPTO_KEY='keycode'
    const iv = crypto
    .createHash("sha256")
    .update(CRYPTO_KEY)
    .digest();
  
    const key = crypto
    .createHash("sha256")
    .update(CRYPTO_KEY)
    .digest();
    
    const resizedIV = Buffer.allocUnsafe(16);
    iv.copy(resizedIV);
    
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes256', key, resizedIV);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(string, 'hex', 'utf8')
    return decrypted;
}
```

Is there a way to convert these code to use cryptoJs library?
Are there equivalent functions or another separate library for doing this?

Comment: The code uses only standard functionalities, e.g. SHA56 or AES-256 in CBC mode. Any reasonable crypto library can do this, including CryptoJS. Note that the posted code is missing the final call and that deriving the IV from the key is a vulnerability.

Comment: But I am unable to figure out the functions in cryptoJs. It seems like it has only few features. I am not really great with cryptography but due to an issue I had to take up this one? Anyway you could help me out here

Comment: The NodeJS code is buggy. An incomplete last plaintext block is not taken into account. Or are your plaintexts guaranteed to have a length equal to an integer multiple of the block size (16 bytes)?

Comment: The CryptoJS documentation provides examples, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#hashing) for SHA256 and [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#custom-key-and-iv) for AES with which an implementation should be feasible. If you are struggling, post your CryptoJS code and describe the problem.